# elastic Search not working for having special character '^(caret symbol)'

Tags: elasticsearch

The problem is any character sequence having boost operator "^(caret symbol)" does not returning any search results.

But as per the below elastic search documentation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

- - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \  characters can be escaped with \ symbol.

Have a requirement to do a contains search using n-gram analyser in elastic search.

Below is the mapping structure of the sample use case and the

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "nGram_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
          },
          "whitespace_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "ngram_tokenizer": {
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit",
              "punctuation",
              "symbol"
            ],
            "min_gram": "2",
            "type": "nGram",
            "max_gram": "20"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "employee": {
      "properties": {
        "employeeName": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have a employee name like below with special characters included
**xyz%^&***

Also the sample query used for the contains search as below

```
GET
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "employeeName": {
              "query": "xyz%^",
              "type": "boolean",
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even if we try to escape as "query": **"xyz%\^"** its errors out. So not able to search any character contains search having "^(caret symbol)"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in `ngram tokenizer` related to [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18388).

Essentially `^` is not considered either   `Symbol |Letter |Punctuation` by `ngram-tokenizer`.
 As a result it tokenizes the input on `^`.

Example: (url encoded xyz%^):

`GET <index_name>/_analyze?tokenizer=ngram_tokenizer&text=xyz%25%5E`

The above result of analyze api shows there is no `^` as shown in the response below :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "xy",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 2,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "xyz",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "xyz%",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "yz",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "yz%",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "z%",
         "start_offset": 2,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 5
      }
   ]
}
```

Since '^' is not indexed therefore there are no matches

Comment: Thanks for the response @keety.